# Detecting missing audio in MOV files

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mov

i'm curious if there is a way to detect if audio is missing or broken from a MOV video file. Recently there was a MOV file which was playable, but the audio was "missing".

I tried ffmpeg to get specific errors but it did not give me any. I only noticed that the audio bitrate was very low, 2kb/s. Apart from checking the audio bitrate is there a way to detect such broken video clips with ffmpeg?

The mising audio could have been caused by an unsuccessful copying of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i movie.avi -af volumedetect -f null -
```

This will print out a histogram telling you the volume in the file